# Ignore specific path in zuul filter rather than general path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I google quite a bit and couldnt get the answer. In my spring-boot application, I have rest endpoints which looks like

```
/v1/book/{bookId}
```

```
/v1/book/{bookId}/reorder
```

I want the zuul filter to ignore the first pattern not the second. 
If I give

```
zuul.ignoredPatterns: /v1/book/**
```

It ignores both. So how to ignore just the first one?

Comment: Have you tried /v1/book/{bookId} ?

Comment: Yes, I tried. If I  give it like that then zuul doesnt ignore both.

Comment: Can u post a minimal project on github which verifies the problem